# How can I show or hide a control based on a select control in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a form that contains a select list box with 3 values - Trade, Sell and Give Away. There is 1 other text box called Sell Price Per Unit which should only be visible when Sell is selected in the select list. How can I achieve this in Blazor Server Side?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="uom">Trade / Sell / Give Away</label>
     <select id="uom" class="form-control" @bind="@ItemForTradeObject.TradeOrSell">
     <option value="">-- Select a Trade/Sell --</option>
     @foreach (Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell tos in (Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell)))
     {
        <option value="@tos">@tos</option>
     }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="taskName">Sell Price Per Unit (£)</label>
    <InputNumber id="sellPrice" class="form-control" @bind-Value="ItemForTradeObject.SellPricePerUnit" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ItemForTradeObject.SellPricePerUnit)" />
</div>
```

Comment: put an @if statement around the markup you want to conditionally show

Comment: @MisterMagoo I can do that but what am I putting in the If? Because Im referring to a control on the page. Something like @if(selectcontrol.value == 'sell')

Comment: You need to check for the value of `ItemForTradeObject.TradeOrSell` and because it's an enum, you need to compare to the enum that should show the other input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add `@if(ItemForTradeObject.TradeOrSell == EnumValueYouWantToShow)` checking if the value is the value on the enum you want.

Please provide the enum `TradeOrSell` so I don't need to guess what is the name of the enum you are using.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="uom">Trade / Sell / Give Away</label>
     <select id="uom" class="form-control" @bind="@ItemForTradeObject.TradeOrSell">
     <option value="">-- Select a Trade/Sell --</option>
     @foreach (Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell tos in (Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell)))
     {
        <option value="@tos">@tos</option>
     }
    </select>
</div>

@* Check if the value equals the enum you want*@
@if(ItemForTradeObject.TradeOrSell == Project.Shared.enums.TradeOrSell.Sell){
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="taskName">Sell Price Per Unit (£)</label>
        <InputNumber id="sellPrice" class="form-control" @bind-Value="ItemForTradeObject.SellPricePerUnit" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ItemForTradeObject.SellPricePerUnit)" />
    </div>
}
```